# Factor unknown levels at runtime while setting labels for known levels at design time

Tags: r, r-factor

Consider a simple function that factors and labels a vector (with unordered levels):

```
  my.factor <- function(data){
    levels = c("d1", "d2", "d3")
    labels = c("Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3")
    factored.data = factor(data, levels, labels)
    factored.data
  }
```

This works well for known levels. But suppose an unknown level is added in the future and we run our function:

```
data = c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d1", "d100")
my.factor(data)
```

The output will be:

```
# [1] Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 Data 1 <NA>  
# Levels: Data 1 Data 2 Data 3
```

However, I want the new, unknown value to be included as a level. That is, I want the output to resemble:

```
# [1] Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 Data 1 d100
# Levels: Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 d100
```

Is there a way to set labels for known levels at design time, while still including new, unknown levels that may be passed to my code at runtime?

Comment: Does the order of the resulting levels matter?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Levels are unordered, I should have specified and have edited the question. Appreciate your clear, concise solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
  my.factor <- function(data){
    levels <- c("d1", "d2", "d3")
    labels <- c("Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3")
    nlevels <- setdiff(unique(data), levels)
    levels<-c(levels, nlevels)
    labels <-c(labels, nlevels)
    factored.data = factor(data, levels, labels)
    factored.data
  }
```

which gives

```
data = c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d1", "d100")
my.factor(data)
# [1] Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 Data 1 d100  
# Levels: Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 d100
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `mapvalues` from the [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) package, which reassigns the specified levels of a factor while leaving others intact:

```
my.factor <- function(data){
    levels = c("d1", "d2", "d3")
    labels = c("Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3")
    plyr::mapvalues(factor(data), levels, labels)
}

my.factor(c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d100"))
```

Answer (score 0):

using `%in%` is one way...

```
 my.factor <- function(data){
    levels = c("d1", "d2", "d3")
    labels = c("Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3")
    extra <- data[!(data %in% levels)]
    if(length(extra) > 0){
    levels = c("d1", "d2", "d3", extra)
    labels = c("Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3", extra)
    }
    factored.data = factor(data, levels, labels)
    factored.data
  }

data <- c("d1", "d2", "d3","d100")
my.factor(data)
#[1] Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 d100  
#Levels: Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 d100

data <- c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d1", "d100")
my.factor(data)
#[1] Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 Data 1 d100  
#Levels: Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 d100
```